# What mesh file types are supported for input by the C++ library CGAL?

Tags: c++, file-io, mesh, cgal

I've searched through the documentation, and it appears that they at least support .off files. http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html

However, I want to know if they allow for input of STL files as well, before I trouble myself with trying to use the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a piece of code in `CGAL-4.6/demo/Polyhedron/` that permits to load an STL file to a `CGAL::Polyhedron_3` object. The demo allows to load an STL file, and then save to an OFF file.

Alternatively, if you need to have a STL-loader inside your own code, you might copy-paste and adapt the existing code.

The file is in `demo/Polyhedron/Polyhedron_demo_stl_plugin.cpp` and it uses an undocumented header file `include/CGAL/IO/Polyhedron_builder_from_STL.h`.

Comment: The demos you receive when you download CGAL?

Comment: Yes: when you download CGAL either from tarballs or from the Windows installer, you get a directory `CGAL-4.6/` that contains several sub-directories: `examples/` for examples, `include/` for headers that contains all the templates declarations/definitions, `src/` for the source files of the CGAL shared libraries, `demo/` for the demos.